# Как открыть файл который нашла команда ls или find (bash)

Tags: bash, fish-shell

Есть команда `find . -type f -newermt "2020-11-13" | tail -n1` 
Которая выводит следующий результат 
  
 **find:** 
команда: `find . -type f -newermt "2020-11-13" | tail -n1`  
вывод: `./XXX.Debug.2020.11.13.log`

или

**ls:**
команда: `ls -tr | tail -n1` 
вывод: `XXX.Debug.2020.11.13.log`

Как не просто отобразить, но и открыть найденный файл в редакторе (к примеру VS Code-e (code))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
editor `ls -tr | tail -n1`

find . -type f -newermt "2020-11-13" | tail -n1 | xargs editor
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @mkkik ls не сработало, а вот find сработал!!! Спасибо! Я забыл упоминать что я эти команды планирую использовать на Windows через Cygwin. Скорее всего ls по этому не сработало (

Comment: @aleksandr barakin Ответ по пойму очень прозрачный! Всё понятно!